# adb uninstall not working for realme device

Tags: android, adb, uninstallation, usb-debugging

I just purchased a Realme phone(Realme 6 pro to be specific) and want to delete several preinstalled apps for obvious reasons.
I did all the essential things which some of you might point out so explicitly stating them:

1. enabled the developer option, turned on USB debugging
2. `adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.heytap.market`(in this instance to remove App Market) gives

   *Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]*

I did everything I could in the last two days exploring through almost everything available on the internet.
I don't want to root the device because it is not even a week old. Any help would be really really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

That mean that the App was installed with root privileges or during the build. Thus you cannot uninstall it.

Start the app and run:

```
adb shell ps -A | grep "com.heytap.market" | cut -f1 -d' '
```

and check the resulted user that run the process. If it's "system" or "root" that mean you cannot uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to delete/disable these applications:

```
adb shell service call package 131 s16 com.heytap.browser i32 0 i32 0
adb shell pm disable com.heytap.browser

adb shell service call package 131 s16 com.heytap.market i32 0 i32 0
adb shell pm disable com.heytap.market

adb shell service call package 131 s16 com.heytap.tas i32 0 i32 0
adb shell pm disable com.heytap.tas
```